# "Ignoring" a dangerous AC level, while performing ADC conversion on DC level

Tags: adc, arc

I need to monitor a plasma cutter's DC voltage. I selected the AD629 from Analog Devices and have a schematic and layout that works on a test bench.

Admittedly, my talents are in software and what I know about EE just makes me dangerous. :)

My concern is that welders and plasma cutters emit a high-frequency AC signal in order to start the arc. Not knowing any better, it seems to me that signal would fry my board. Although I've seen torch-height controllers and similar and see no obvious technique for "shielding" the PCB from this.

I am assuming that a 5K volt AC signal would happily create arcs anywhere the POS and NEG lines are very close -- such as on a PCB.

How is this working?

Comment: You need EMI filters on the input line. What frequency is the start-frequency?

Comment: It can vary with different makers, but the usual number I've found is "5,000 VAC at 2 MHz".

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that components that would form a lowpass filter would do the job? Something that blocks signals above 1MHz, for example.

Comment: That's the idea, but it's going to be tough to create a LPF which works to 5kVAC.

Comment: I found 2 resistors and a cap rated for 10kVAC. Limited choices, but they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like a low pass filter with a high-voltage rated resistor to the input. The HF start is in the ~1MHz range so filtering that out is not difficult.

Looking at the block diagram of my AC/DC TIG welder with HF start, they monitor the voltage from the other side of the HF coupling transformer. Image from [here](https://elektrotanya.com/thermal_arc_185tsw_ac_dc_cc_eng-om.pdf/download.html#dl).

[image]

Comment: I studied those PDFs. When you say "they monitor the voltage from the other side of the HF coupling transformer" -- how are you concluding this? Also, why would it matter where in the circuit this is monitored, doesn't this AC signal appear everywhere along both cables?

Comment: Nothing is connected to the output terminal side of CC1 except the output '-' terminal. The CC1 secondary is in series with the output voltage.

Comment: Meaning that the injected AC signal only appears on one side of CC1 ?

Comment: Yes, because the other side is more closely coupled to ground/chassis potential (by parts that are not explicitly shown).

Comment: I'm wondering why the arc doesn't jump between IC pins or between 0.100" headers and the like. After all, it jumps through air a fairly good distance.

Comment: Because the high voltage does not exist between IC pins or between pins on 2.54mm centres. ;-)

Comment: OK, thank you. My PCB would have leads on the POS and NEG of the plasma machine, and then into a header that is 0.100". But if I'm following what's been said here, it sounds like a 4.7k resistor and a 47nF cap would give me a solid low pass which would eliminate all of it.

Comment: 4.7K is way too low. Think many megs and rated for many kV.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what Spehro was saying would be needed for a high-side monitor, click for full-size:

[image: Monitoring DC level with high AC pulses present]

It would have to be built on a circuit board, with adequate spacing around the HV components to avoid any corona, arc-over, or radiated energy from getting into anything else.

Note that the DC level will likely be very low, as plasma is inherently very conductive. I'd call this all a guess, with lots of experimentation required. You may find that C1 removes too many fast transients and C1/D1 leakage current requires correction. Inject 10.00vDC into it and adjust the gain of the op-amps for 10v out.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I found some 10kV resistors and caps. I used two 10M -- one on each lead from the welder. Paranoia, I guess. Or ignorance. I have been able to block the AC and get only the DC component into the opamp. So far, it's working. Nothing's caught on fire. I used a separate breadboard for the HV stuff and was very careful to keep it away from everything. The post-filter DC run is about 6 inches.

Comment: Curious, how low is the DC component? Even at 50 or 100A, plasma isn't very resistive.

Comment: By "low", I assume you mean volts and/or amps. The voltage ranges between 5 and 70 VDC. It depends on the length of the plasma. I haven't been monitoring current, I assume the machine is set up to allow the max that the user has entered.